# Using type traits in C++ template functions, is it possible to convert a value to a T of the same type?

Tags: c++, templates, casting, c++17, type-traits

I'm trying to write a template function like this

```
template<typename T>
T doSomething() { 
    //Code

    if (std::is_same<T, int>::value) { 
        return getInt();   // A library function returning an int
    } else if (std::is_same<T, bool>::value) {
        return getBool();  // A library function returning a bool
    } else { 
        throw;
    }
}
```

that calls different functions depending on the template parameter given and returns a value  which, at runtime, is guaranteed to have the same type as T.
However, the compiler gives me this error: `'return': cannot convert from 'int' to 'T'`
I guess I could use something like `reinterpret_cast`, but this seems to be unsafe and bad practice in this scenario.

So, is there a way to return different types from a template function depending on the template parameter in C++?

Comment: The simplest answer relies on a C++17 feature.  Are you using C++17 or later?

Comment: @DrewDormann Yes, I am using C++17.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, is there a way to return different types from a template function
> depending on the template parameter in C++?

Yes, you can use C++17 [`constexpr if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if)

```
template<typename T>
T doSomething() { 
    //Code

    if constexpr (std::is_same<T, int>::value) { 
        return getInt();   // A library function returning an int
    } else if constexpr (std::is_same<T, bool>::value) {
        return getBool();  // A library function returning a bool
    } else { 
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can also shorten `std::is_same<...>::value` to `std::is_same_v<...>`.

Answer (score 3):

Besides *constexpr if*(for pre-c++17) you can also use **explicit specialization** as shown below:

```
template<typename T> //primary template
T doSomething() { 
    std::cout<<"throw version"<<std::endl;
    throw;
}

template<> //specialization for int
int doSomething<int>() { 
    std::cout<<"int version"<<std::endl;
    return getInt();
}

template<>//specialization for bool
bool doSomething<bool>() { 
    std::cout<<"bool version"<<std::endl;
    return getBool();
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/ZRFgMhXsW).